# problems with firejail --overlay

Tags: lubuntu

I´ve got a problem with firejail. 
In principle this sandbox works quite well. I can start a browser (firefox/midori) and other applications as well (like rhythmbox).
What I want to do now is use the overlay-functionality: firejail --overlay firefox.
Yet that doesn´t work.

Firefox itself produces the following message: " Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible". Yet that can´t be. Without firejail there´s no problem and even "firejail firefox" works well.
The following message is taken from the terminal:

```
rosika@rosika-Lenovo-H520e ~> firejail --overlay firefox
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-mgmt.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-secret.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Warning: --overlay and --noroot are mutually exclusive, noroot disabled
Parent pid 2362, child pid 2363
OverlayFS configured in /home/rosika/.firejail/2362 directory
Warning: cannot find home directory
***
*** Warning: cannot whitelist Downloads directory
***     Any file saved will be lost when the sandbox is closed.
***     Please create a proper Downloads directory for your application.
***
Blacklist violations are logged to syslog
Warning: failed to unmount /sys

Child process initialized
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

parent is shutting down, bye..
```

As far as I know --overlay has been working as of kernel version 3.18. As I have 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 there shouldn´t be any problems.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance.
Rosika

P.S.:
System: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)